# Kerning subscripts

Tags: fonts, equations

```
\newcommand{\EQ}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\EN}{\end{equation}}
\EQ
\vec{F}_{TOTAL} = \vec{F}_g + \vec{F}_{OTHER}
\EN
```

The small g after F looks like it's hanging in space.
Using

```
\EQ
\vec{F}_{\hspace{-0.2ex}TOTAL} = \vec{F}_{\hspace{-0.4ex}g} +     
\vec{F}_{\hspace{-0.3ex}OTHER}
\EN
```

works, but seems a little inefficient, and requires different numbers for different subscripts. Is there any other way of dealing with this?

added: minimal working program with \mkern

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}




\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm} %, amssymb}
\newcommand{\EQ}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\EN}{\end{equation}}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}  


\newcommand{\vecdd}[1]{\ddot{\mathbf{#1}}} %bold vector with double derivatvie dot


\begin{document}

\EQ
\vec{F}_{\mkern -2mu TOTAL} = \vec{F}_{\mkern -5mu gn} + \vec{F}_{\mkern -2mu OTHER}
\EN
\end{document}
```

Comment: I prefer the default look to your kerned version, especially for the `OTHER` term.  Also, you should use `\mkern{-`x `mu}` (where x is a number) instead of `\hspace`, because `\hspace` inserts stretchable glue, which you don't want with a kern. A `mu` is the math unit of kerning, as opposed the `\kern` which kerns text.

Comment: The subscripts starting with capital letters do look OK, but the uncapitalized g and n looked a little lost in space. The \hspace worked, but I think the \mkern is better; at the least it requires less typing. I'm a little new to latex, so I'm not exactly sure what this 'glue' you speak of is, but if it is saved, I'm all for it.

Comment: You need no kern, but that those subscripts are enclosed in `\textnormal`, because they should be in upright type; definitely not in math italic, in any case.